# Printing 2D ArrayList derived from a class which has int and String

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a task to make an `ArrayList` which is derived from class data contains three elements, which I have done, however I can not seem to get it to print the array as I have tried a few things. Heres what I have:

This is the class derived from.

```
 package lab5;

//import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Data {

    private String mName;
      private int mAge;
      public Data(int age, String name) {
         mName = name;
         mAge = age;
      }
      public String getName() {
         return mName;
      }
      public int getAge() {
          return mAge;
      }

}
```

This is the class with mai:

```
package lab5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CS1702_Lab5 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        ArrayList<Data> array_list = new ArrayList<Data>();

        array_list.add(new Data(21, "Fred"));
        array_list.add(new Data(43, "Jo"));
        array_list.add(new Data(37, "Zoe"));


    }
}
```

How do I get to print whats in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: override `toSting` in Data class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `toString()` method in your `Data` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            "mName='" + mName + '\'' +
            ", mAge=" + mAge +
            '}';
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
System.out.println(array_list);
```

in your main class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for loop` to iterate over the list and use your `Data` class methods to get data.

```
for(Data item : array_list){
    System.out.println("Name = " + item.getName() + "Age = " + item.getAge());
}
```